# not able to get return array values

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am new to the Laravel framework. How can I get values from an array?

This is my code:

```
  $output['device_type']=$arrout['equipment']['fabricat']['fabricat_name'].' '.$arrout['equipment']['model']['model'].''.$arrout['equipment']['type']['type'];
```

Here equipment model and Fabricat are working fine. Type only not working but

`var_dump($arrout['equipment']['type']['type']);die;`

returns the correct values: `string 'Tilhengermontert'` (length=16)

Comment: but I got the Issue for Undefined index: type

Comment: CertificateReport.php line 133:

Comment: Please be specific what you want to ask and post the complete code.

Comment: Debug. Dump out ```$arrout``` and you should see what the problem is for yourself.

Comment: Try to ```var_dump($arrout);``` and inspect if all the indexes are present in it.

Comment: Hi Friend's I got the answer. thank you so much  for your reply